# how to stylize 3 divs to fit relatively on 100% window size

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in placing divs relatively with each other. I placed them 3 in a row and 3 in each column (the first column is `140px`, 2nd is `320px` and 3rd is `500px` from the `left`) with each other by pixel formatting in 100% window size but it needs scrolling to see them in any other window size. I want it to arrange themselves accordingly as the window size changes. The code I wrote is given as follows

```css
#box1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ac536f;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 162px;
  left: 140px;
}

#box2 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ac536f;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 162px;
  left: 320px;
}

#box3 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ac536f;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 162px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUksMAlXQ9w"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" />DIV1</a>
</div>
<div id="box2">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hEMAPoW3B8"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" />DIV2</a>
</div>
<div id="box3">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iINlkySuCDI"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" />DIV3</a>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="box1">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXB5jeceKic"><img src="thumbnail4.jpg" />DIV4</a>
</div>
<div id="box2">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tK4pTRySWCM"><img src="thumbnail5.jpg" />DIV5</a>
</div>
<div id="box3">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdH68x36Vxc"><img src="thumbnail6.png" />DIV6</a>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="box1">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_al3HCUNrKo"><img src="thumbnail7.jpeg" />DIV7</a>
</div>
<div id="box2">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua5rZXKj4q0&t=27s"><img src="thumbnail8.png" />DIV8</a>
</div>
<div id="box3">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6PgE_igVz8"><img src="thumbnail9.png" />DIV9</a>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• You should read up on [flex-box](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/). The flex-box does the layout for you and sorts out any kind of wrapping.
• You should never use `<br/>` if you want to do the page responsive. Let the CSS take care of any row wrapping.
• Using `id` is just for unique objects. Use CSS classes instead if you want to apply the same CSS to several elements.

I made the boxes 60x60px to easier display the wrapping on smaller devices.

```css
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ac536f;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUksMAlXQ9w"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" />DIV1</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hEMAPoW3B8"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" />DIV2</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iINlkySuCDI"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" />DIV3</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXB5jeceKic"><img src="thumbnail4.jpg" />DIV4</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tK4pTRySWCM"><img src="thumbnail5.jpg" />DIV5</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdH68x36Vxc"><img src="thumbnail6.png" />DIV6</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_al3HCUNrKo"><img src="thumbnail7.jpeg" />DIV7</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua5rZXKj4q0&t=27s"><img src="thumbnail8.png" />DIV8</a>
  <a class="box" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6PgE_igVz8"><img src="thumbnail9.png" />DIV9</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height to :

```
    height: 30vh;
```

That means you set the height to 30% of the screen what the user sees